# Openlayers ratio of the original image size vs displayed image size

Tags: openlayers

I was trying to get ratio between original image size vs currently displayed image size in openlayers. Is there is a way get this calculation?

Comment: as a feature of image? if so, unless you limit or set its scale or size, image displays with its original size, doesn't it?

Comment: I have used zoomify as source and load image through tileUrlFunction function.so initially image loaded as tiles. What i need is comparison between current loaded image size and original image size when user zooms. I only have original imagewidth and height.

Comment: I was able to do this feature by calculating the resolutions of the image